# Finding which class called the remote method

Tags: java, security, permissions, rmi

I'm learning *Java RMI* and I'm trying to do an assignment which requires me to have two different client types interacting with the same server.

One of the two clients has more privleges than the other one, and this means that the first one is the only one that can call a certain method.

Let's make a quick sample:

we have 3 classes:

- Server
- AdminClient
- UserClient

*Server* exports a method called *doSomething()* which **cannot** be called from *UserClient* but only from *AdminClient*.

Is there a way to do something like this?

I know that, since I'm writing the code, it's quite easy to write the *UserClient* and stop him from calling that method, but I'm asking more something on server-side security, provided that the client's code can be modified to call *doSomething()*.

The *doSomething()* should be like:

```
void doSomething(){
    Class caller = getCaller().getClass();
    if (caller instanceof UserClient) return;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Im not sure what youre trying to do. If you wanna check which type the caller is, and they dont fall under the same hierarchy, `instanceof` seems to be what you're looking for. But seeing how its already in your example, what more do you need?

Comment: There's no `getCaller()` method, I invented it just to make the example, and this is the missing part :)

Comment: `getCaller()` is the missing part? Im still not sure on what youre trying to do :s i would have to see how your client/server architecture is. I need to know if its an asynchronous server, or if youre using blocking io or not, and how youre receiving data from clients (do you put all incomming data into a list, then sort it out? Or do you handle incomming data right away)

Comment: With a network that uses a thread for each connection (usually due to blocking io), data is usually handled instantly and on the thread it came in on, making it very easy to filter things specific to that user. Networks that use nonblocking io handles multiple users on the same thread, which requires more detailed filtering. Please give some kind simple version of your network architecture

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is not clear but actually is quite simpler than what it looks: I need a way to make the _Server_ know which class has called its remote method. So, if the _Server_ exports the method _doSomething()_ and this can be called from both _ClientA_ and _ClientB_, I need a way to make the _Server_ know that _doSomething_ was called by an instance of _ClientA_ rather than an instance of _ClientB_. Is it clear now?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have enough points to downvote this question.

Comment: If you want to have more points try to write something useful ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't. Your server won't know who the remote client is.

I suggest placing your domain logic behind 2 different remote services, one implementing a UserInterface and one implementing an AdminInterface. Hand out the UserInterface stub to the UserClient, hand out the AdminInterface stub to the AdminClient.

Comment: Create two different stubs how? Any given remote object has exactly one stub class.

Comment: I think he was suggesting to create two different servers, one to be used by the _AdminClient_ and the other for the _UserClient_

Comment: @StepTNT I'm commenting on what he actually wrote. If that's not what're meant, let him fix it.

Comment: I know, I was just explaining why I accepted his answer :)

Comment: well, I edited it. I hope it is a better answer now.